# Submersion preserves openness

Tags: differential-topology

Can you help me with this, but please don't post solutions, just give hints :)

$M, N$ are manifolds, $f : M → N$ is a submersion, and $U \subset M$ is open, then
$f(U)$ is open in $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Submersions are locally projections.